# Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'string'

Tags: python

This is the file that my class is in

```
#8/23/2020
#Class file

class Questions:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

This is my main body of text that runs with the attribute error

```
#8/23/20
#Multiple Choice quiz
import random
from question_class import Questions
#These are my variables that I will use in the question_prompts array
number3 = random.randint(1,100)
number4 = random.randint(1,100)
number5 = random.randint(1,10)
number6 = random.randint(1,10)
number7 = random.randint(50,100)
number8 = random.randint(12,50)

answer3 = int(number3) + int(number4)
answer4 = int(number5) * int(number6)
answer5 = int(number7) - int(number8)



question_prompts = [  #This is my array for the question prompts
    "Question 1:\nIn the directions NWSE what does E stand for?\n(a)Eagle\n(b)Eric\n(c)East\n(d)Enter\n",
    "Question 2:\n(T/F) Tomatoes are fruits\n(T)\n(F)",
    "Question 3:\nWhat is " + str(number3) + " + " + str(number4) + "?\n",
    "Question 4:\nWhat is " + str(number5) + " x " + str(number6) + "?\n",
    "Question 5:\nWhat is " + str(number7) + " - " + str(number8) + "?\n"
]

questions = [ #This is my array for my question class prompts and answers
    Questions(question_prompts[0],"c"),
    Questions(question_prompts[1],"f"),
    Questions(question_prompts[2],str(answer3)),
    Questions(question_prompts[3],str(answer4)),
    Questions(question_prompts[4],str(answer5)),
]

def run_test(questions): #This is my function to run the quiz
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(questions.answer)
        if answer == questions.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You scored " + str(score) + "/" + len(questions.prompts))
run_test(questions)
```

I am new to coding, and this project is a multiple choice quiz project. I followed Mike Dane's tutorial and tried to make it dynamic, but the error showed up. Please use beginner friendly words

Answer (score 0):

For a start, `answer == questions.answer` is wrong, because `questions` (with an `s`) is a list of questions, not a question. It should be `answer == question.answer` (without an `s`).

Secondly, I'm not sure how difficult this quiz is going to be when the question just gives you the answers rather than actually asking you the question:

```
answer = input(questions.answer)
```

I think you probably want to pass in `question.prompt` instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in `run_test`.  The following should fix them:

```
def run_test(questions): #This is my function to run the quiz
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You scored " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)))
run_test(questions)
```

Changes:

1. `input(questions.answer)` -> `input(question.prompt)`
   [Note there are 2 changes here]
2. `questions.answer` -> `question.answer`
3. `len(questions.prompts)` -> `str(len(questions))` [Note there are 2 changes here]